# Angular: registerLocaleData with en-US-POSIX and currency

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand why the dollar sign does not show up when I register locale data with en-US-POSIX while using currency pipe?

My application allows for the user to change language, upon doing so I am registering the locale data, maybe en-US-POSIX is not the correct default locale data for en-US?

Assuming this code

TS:

```
import locale_en_US from '@angular/common/locales/en-US-POSIX';

registerLocaleData(locale_en_US, 'en-US');
```

template:

```
{{ 10.25 | currency }}
```

The output (no $ sign):

```
10.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that 'en-US-POSIX' does not print the currency symbol.
Use 'en' instead.